# List subscription users in a drop-down list using ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to get subscription users and showing them into a drop-down list using an ARM Template. Any ideas? Thanksss.

I want to show users inside a drop-down list in the UI Template, i tried using powershell and az cli but i need to list users in the UI template.

Comment: Is this what you are looking?[Image](https://i.imgur.com/zSZS2MR.png)

Comment: @Harshitha Yes, but displaying the users.